# CSS position:fixed not fixed in Mobile Safari... again

Tags: jquery, css, mobile-safari, css-position

Friends,

I'm still sorta new to jQuery and am having a helluva time figuring out how to get this thing to stick to the top of my Mobile Safari window. I've tried iScroll, I've tried jQuery Mobile, I've read about tricks that make it hide and disappear on scroll, etc.. but I just can't seem to get it to work. All I want is for the little nav box to stay at the top of my screen while I swipe up and down the page. As it is now, when I swipe down the page to scroll, the fixed element slides up the page with the content. If somebody can show me where I'm missing something, I'd appreciate it.

Here's a working fiddle for Safari that doesn't like Mobile Safari:
http://jsfiddle.net/gZ9ze/

It's basically a standard div with a fixed position that, when clicked, slides up to a negative top value. When clicked again it slides down to 0 top value.

Thanks in advance,
Layne

CSS

```
.navigationBox {
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}
.sliderButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
}
.storyContent {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var easingMethod = "easeOutCubic";
var opened = true;
function openNav() {
    $(".navigationBox").animate({
        top: 0
    }, 500, easingMethod);
    opened = true;
};
function closeNav() {
    $(".navigationBox").animate({
        top: -75
    }, 500, easingMethod);
    opened = false;
};
$('.sliderButton').click(function () {
    if (opened == true) {
        closeNav();
    } else {
        openNav();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigationBox">
    <div class="dummyNav">Dummy Nav Elements<br/>which will do other things.</div>
    <div class="sliderButton">Click here to slide me</div>
</div>
<div class="storyContent">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus feugiat porttitor porttitor. Ut tortor quam, convallis ut scelerisque eget, dignissim eu lorem. Ut ullamcorper velit a tellus iaculis rhoncus laoreet lectus cursus. Fusce et leo at magna pulvinar consectetur in vitae lacus. Morbi lorem odio, fermentum vitae tristique placerat, varius ac massa. Mauris egestas, mauris ac dictum consequat, turpis dui vehicula velit, et ornare ante dolor sed libero. 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know position fixed doesn't work on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Position: fixed doesn't work on mobile browsers. You have to simulate this with js. Set position: absolute on .navigationBox and bind on the scroll event to update the offset from the top.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
   $(".navigationBox").css('top', $(document).scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Drat! My experience has been that divs like that slide around and then move back into position after the scroll is complete. Is there a startScroll or something where I can hid the navigationBox on startScroll and then show it when it's moved back into position? I'd rather it just hide and show than slide all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can add event handlers to 'touchstart' and 'touchend' to hide and show your div.